# How to connect the SQL Server to node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

As I am using SQL Server 18 and nodeJs version12, below code snippet I tried and I get an error shown below.

Code snippet:

```
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
var config = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  connectionString: 'Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Server=Server_name;Database=DBname;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
};

sql.connect(config)
.then(function() {
 console.log("done");
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Error :

> ConnectionError: Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> at C:\Users\user\test-app\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js:56:17
>   at Immediate. (C:\Users\user\test-app\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:362:15)
>   at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
>         code: undefined,
>         name: 'ConnectionError'

Comment: I think you should be using a better npm package like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql to connect to mssql using node. It has better documentation and is more reliable. However, In your code, I cannot see any username/password passed in the options. Is the db open?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **18** - we have 2012 (v11), 2014 (v12), 2016 (v13), 2017 (v14) and 2019 (v15) - take your pick

Comment: Make sure you have network permission to connect to DB server from local host if you are trying from local host.

Comment: I can confirm that `mssql/msnodesqlv8` works fine. You are getting a standard SQL Server connection error, for which there are many troubleshooting guides. Strangely, I could _only_ connect on host `127.0.0.1`. The normal connection host names didn't work (`localhost` and my actual computer name)